# Is it possible to create a flow that creates an opportunity and an event from the account screen?

Tags: opportunity, account, visual-workflow, activities

I am building out a new SFDC org for my new company and i want to use flows to try to cut down on my users using multiple objects, i have tried this in the past but a few years back in a different business but flows were in the early stages and not so user friendly, i am now hoping they are a bit more user friendly and have a few more features.

So before i go off to try build something that is not even possible i thought id ask first :)

Is it possible to create a flow that creates an opportunity and and event from the account screen? i just want to populate it with basic info if i can pull this off i can build my new system using as many flows as possible to save on users crying that they dont like having to click lots of different objects

Any info would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

JR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

Long version - you'll need to use a Fast Lookup element to get whatever details you need from the Account and then a couple of Create Record elements in your flow, one for the Opportunity and one for the Event (remember to store the Opportunity Id in a variable for use in creating your event). Plus of course whatever other logic you need, but that should be the basic building blocks for what you're after.

You can then use a custom Detail Page Button which opens your flow URL (e.g. `/flow/YOUR_FLOW_NAME_HERE?PARAMETER_1=XXXX&PARAMETER_2=XXXX`) on the Account screen to kick the process off.

Flow is immensely powerful once you get the hang of it, I would recommend watching the training video(s) that appear the first time you open the Flow Designer if you've not used it before.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex i will do that now before i start, im assuming a bit will have changed in the last 2 years, i think if i can get my head around the basics i can nail this for the business, i have just asked my SF Dev mate if i build out the flow can he fill in on the part i have become stuck with in the past, which has always been mainly the same things look ups and linking the data to existing record or creating a new record this should be second anture to him i assume as hes used to doing it in triggers and classes, 2 years later my skills and patients should have improved i hope :)

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest using a regular Record Lookup rather than a Fast Lookup. Fast Lookups are designed for sObject Variables and Collections, and while you could do this with an sObject Variable, it's simpler and easier for beginners to use regular variables and Record Lookups.

Comment: @markross__c I suggested a Fast Lookup as I'm expecting a reasonable number of fields on the Account will need to be used. Although I agree that if you only need 2 or 3 fields then a regular Record Lookup will suffice and has less pitfalls (e.g. formula field values).

Comment: Hi Guys, the account will already be created i just want to have a button or link toa  flow to create a basic opp with minimal info and attach an event with minimal info, i am going to be trying this out this morning so i will post my results, i installed some flow samples pack which should help bring me up to speed :)

Comment: Hi Guys

i made some progress, yesterday i worked through the work books which was a good refresher, but now i have ran into a few problems,

long story short

i have now created a button on the account screen to create an opportunity, i have populated a default name for the opps created, the mount and start date populate fine 
but my 2 issues are, (next comment)

Comment: the opps are not being created against the existing account i am trying to create them from, i am assuming i need to do a lookup to the account first somehow? 

The other issue is the stages wont populate with the one picked it is populating with a default stage, this is what was initially stopping me from creating anything i have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work, i have my picklist for stages an a choice dropdown.

i have done some reading and some people are saying that flows dont update picklist fields, is this true?

any feed back would be great guys

Comment: @JRogue It's probably worth posting all of this as a new question (with a screenshot of what you have so far). Some pointers for now: You need to create an 'Input' variable for your AccountId and then use a URL parameter to set it (see my answer). When filling things in on screens you need a separate assignment step to store them in variables/SObject variables before you add them to the database.

Comment: Thanks Alex i will give this a try now, then if im still stuck create  a new question thanks for the fast response :)